# In the terminal what does "/path/to/file number" do?

Tags: linux, terminal, macros

There are a series of commands used to launch some code I'm working with.

They are an absolute path followed by the number 0.

e.g.

> /foo/bar/goo 0

Currently its not working, its just gives the error that no such file of directory exists. What is it trying to do?

(Apologies if this should be on stack overflow, I wasn't sure)

Comment: Hi Jekowl. I'm sorry, but as asked, *this is simply unanswerable* in any meaningful way. Linux systems don't use file extensions (some software might look at them, but the OS and shell doesn't); they are just a part of the file name. You give us nothing to go on other than a clearly anonymized path. Any answer to this as asked is going to be *purely speculative*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling the macro file that the command was found in is possibly irrelevant. If I enter a path, then a number, into the terminal (or bash) is this some sort of standard instruction? What's it meant to do?

Comment: It passes a parameter (the string `0`) to `/foo/bar/goo`. Try for example `/usr/bin/stat 0`, `/bin/echo 0`, `/bin/cat 0`, `/bin/ln 0` etc. What a random command does with a given parameter is unknowable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks, that makes sense. I will edit the question to remove mentions of macro files, could you post this an an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the absolute path is executable on your shell, that shell will invoke it and pass "0" as a parameter. If the executable is expecting / using the positional parameter $1, it will use "0", otherwise it will ignore it.

If you're getting the error "No such file or directory", either `/foo/bar/goo` does not exist or you don't have privileges on it, or when it runs it looks for a file that does not exist or which you don't have privileges on.
Pasting here what you're trying to do on the shell (+ the error message) might help understanding what's going on.

On Linux, you could run `strace /foo/bar/goo 0` to see what's going on system-wise when you run the script.